# Altering a continuuous stream of ascii data (amending it with time, for example)

Tags: command-line, stream

I have [a sound level meter](http://sigrok.org/wiki/CEM_DT-8852), which, with the help of the great [`sigrok-cli`](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Main_Page), spits out it's reading via the commandline:

```
# sigrok-cli --driver cem-dt-885x:conn=/dev/ttyUSB1\
--output-format analog --continuous |cut -c 6-12
42.7000
42.5999
42.7000
42.5999
42.5000
(...)
```

I would like to "amend" this continuous stream of data with a few extra things, most importantly the time of the reading to something like this:

```
20140111-190800 42.7000
20140111-190800 42.5999
20140111-190801 42.7000
20140111-190801 42.5999
20140111-190802 42.5000
(...)
```

So far I have tried

```
# sigrok-cli --driver cem-dt-885x:conn=/dev/ttyUSB1\
 --output-format analog --continuous |cut -c 6-12|\
 (while read r ; do echo "$(date +%Y%M%d-%H%M%S) $r"; done)
```

but this *a)* only outputs the data after pressing `Ctrl-c` and *b)* does not change the time (ie. it always shows the time from when I started the command).

In a second step I'd like to round the values to only one digit after the decimal, but that's mostly for beautifying the output (but could possibly be done "while we are at it", ie. while the output is handled in some sort anyway:

```
20140111-190800 42.7
20140111-190800 42.6
20140111-190801 42.7
20140111-190801 42.6
20140111-190802 42.5
(...)
```

Any help, pointer etc. are, as always, highly appreciated.

**Edit 1**
The output I get from @AmokHuginnsson 's code:

```
(...)
43.70 19:58:33
43.50 19:58:33
43.30 19:58:33
43.10 19:58:33
43.00 19:58:33
42.80 19:58:33
42.70 19:58:33
42.50 19:58:34
42.30 19:58:34
42.20 19:58:34
42.10 19:58:34
41.90 19:58:34
41.80 19:58:34
(...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to your problem, first you have to disable buffering on program that  outputs data, second you could use something more sophisticated to transform your data, i.e.

```
stdbuf -o 0 ./a.out | perl -nl -e 'use POSIX; printf ( "%s %.2f\n", strftime( "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S", localtime ), $_ )'
```

Where ./a.out is some program that outputs one float per line.
I don't have your program so I wrote something to test it with:

```
[amok@vegeta](2/1)~/$ cat tick.cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main( int, char** ) {
        srand( time( NULL ) );
        while ( true ) {
                int d( rand() );
                d || ( d = 1 );
                cout << static_cast<double>( rand() ) / d << "\n";
                sleep( 1 );
        }
        return ( 0 );
}
```

BTW, stdbuf is part of the GNU Coreutils, it also available on FreeBSD.
You could also use unbuffer program which is part of expect package, i.e.

```
unbuffer ./a.out | perl -nl -e 'use POSIX; printf ( "%s %.2f\n", strftime( "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S",` localtime ), $_ )
```

Explaining perl part as per request.

There are two parts that maybe of interest of OP.

First is the line format `"%.2f %s\n"` which is standard C printf() style format string,
second is time format, again time format is the same format as in C strftime() call.
Just remember to order printf arguments to reflect the order of particular format items.

`man 3 printf` and `man 3 strftime` are good references about both functions.

Comment: Works as advertised - Thank you! Could you elaborate a bit on your `perl` line? I get the time after the output and might want to change the time format a bit later (the output I get is pasted above as "edit 1". Specifically - how do I get the unbuffered line in anything else then `perl` (ie. `bash`'s `$something`-variable)? Again - Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer to exactly match your requested output format.

Comment: And unbuffering has nothing to do with perl. You may use any text processing language you want, also bash, I used perl cause is was simpler for me to accommodate manipulation of data stream that you requested. Unbuffering is required for any text processor to get "live" data from your program, normally programs buffer its stdout which makes live processing impossible.